# no platform available for current project in Delphi 10.3.3

Tags: delphi

I restarted Delphi 10.3.3 and whether I open an existing project or a brand new project I get:

No platform available for current project.

There is nothing in the drop down menu for the platforms.

Comment: Sounds like you need to reinstall Delphi.

Comment: Reinstallation seems like a drastic action

Comment: @David Indeed, it can be dramatic to have to rebuild your IDE and all its plugins and packages. But this sort of issue, especially if it happens when creating a brand new project, is likely to be deeply rooted. However, perhaps removing any third-party extensions from the IDE might be a better first step.

Comment: What happens when you try to create various other types of projects? Such as a service application, or dll, or different project types in general? Same issue?

Comment: If you did an online install from the ESD, you can simply use the platform manager to install whatever platforms you want. If you used the ISO, then you might want to start the installation from the ISO again.

Comment: Just for fun I added the C++ compiler as a platform. The others are already check as installed in the installer window. It installed the 32bit C++ compiler and then complained that my serial number (correctly) is not good for that platform.

I can open any new or existing project and no platforms are shown.

Comment: Deleting the expired field test license did not help. The license reappeared when I next ran Delphi.

Deleting both licenses got rid of the field test license but the "no platform available" persists.

Answer (score 1):

Completing removing Delphi 10.3.3 and installing it again fixed the issue.